# LISP parameter binding

Tags: parameters, binding, lisp, common-lisp

I have to define a **LISP** function that assigns to a parameter the result of another function, like this:

```
(defun assign-param (x)
  (defparameter param (generic-funct x)))
```

the result of assign-param is `PARAM`, at the first call. If i do another call, the function assign-param returns again `PARAM`, but this way:

```
Warning: (DEFVAR PARAM) defined more than once in 
C:\Users\****\Desktop\****\****.lisp.
PARAM
```

I tried using `defvar` instead of `defparameter` with the same result.

Is there a way to avoid this warning message?

Is there a way to auto-generate other parameters if one already exists?
(ex: if param is already in memory, assign to param1, param2...)

Comment: It seems like an odd pattern. Are you sure you got the assignment right? Parameters could mean arguments and it could be about partial evaluation of something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You are doing something terribly wrong.

[`defvar` and `defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) are
["top-level" forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_t.htm#top_level_form).

There is no reason to use them inside a function.

What you might want to do is something like

```
(defvar *param*)
(defun assign-param (x)
  (setq *param* (generic-funct x))
  '*param*) ; so that `assign-param` returns the symbol instead of the new value, like `defvar`
```

However, your last question about `param1`, `param2` &c makes little
sense (yes, it is possible to do it, and, no, you do *not* want to do it).

## What you might want to be doing

You appear to want to have a set of global parameters, set dynamically from, say, environment or a config file.

There are two main way to do this: hash tables and packages.

### [Hash Tables](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_.htm)

Simple and straighforward; associate any value with any string:

```
(defvar *parameters* (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
(defun param-value (param-name)
  (gethash param-name *parameters*))
(defun (setf param-value) (new-value param-name)
  (setf (gethash param-name *parameters*) new-value))
(param-value "foo")
==> NIL; NIL
(setf (param-value "foo") "bar")
==> "bar"
(param-value "foo")
==> "bar"; T
(defun delete-param (param-name)
  (remhash param-name *parameters*))
```

Note that you should modify `param-value` to signal an error if the second value of [`gethash`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gethas.htm) is `nil`, i.e., the parameter does not exist.

### [Packages](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_.htm)

More involved, but you can associate more "stuff" with your parameter objects:

```
(defvar *parameters* (make-package "parameters" :use ()))
(defun param-value (param-name)
  (multiple-value-bind (param status) (find-symbol param-name *parameters*)
    (unless status
      (error "Parameter %s does not exist" param-name))
    (symbol-value param)))
(defun (setf param-value) (new-value param-name)
  (setf (symbol-value (intern param-name *parameters*)) new-value))
(defun delete-param (param-name)
  (multiple-value-bind (param status) (find-symbol param-name *parameters*)
    (when status
      (unintern param))))
```

The major advantage of this approach is the integration of [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) with the packages which would make config file parsing easier.

A minor advantage is that you can store not just a [value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_5.htm), but also a [function](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fdefin.htm) and a [property list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_4.htm) in your parameter.

Comment: Ty i understood!
Another thing, is there a way to return  `*param*` as result of the function `assign-param`?

Comment: Sure, just make `'*param*` the last form of `assign-param`.

Comment: I tried, pop-up tells me: ` (QUOTE *PARAM*) -- variable name must be a symbol` , sorry for the time loss

Comment: Yep, this is what happens when you so `(setq 'foo ...)`. This is _not_ what I said though (see edit).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(defvar *param*) ;; at the top level: define the variable

;; Now actually just a pure assignment in the function now
(defun assign-param (x)
  (setf *param* (generic-funct x)))
```

I added the `*` "earmuffs", because I can't in good conscience introduce a dynamic variable without; my good name is attached to this answer.

**Really, why though?** Why hide an assignment side effect behind a function. Its almost certainly better to document the `*param*` variable and let the caller do the assignment itself.

Wrapping a Lisp dynamic variable behind this sort of access wall only cripples it.

Lisp lets us do this:

```
;; locally re-bind variable
(let ((*param* (some-value)))
  (code)
  ...))
```

the `(code)` body will execute with `*param*` having the value from `(some-value)`. When the `let` terminates, the previous value is restored, no matter how it terminates. The variable is still global: the altered value is seen inside functions called out of the body, not just by forms that are lexically scoped in the `let`, as with a lexical variable.

(The reason `*param*` is treated this way is that the `defvar` and `defparameter` forms specially mark the symbol for this type of binding and scoping. It becomes a "special variable". And that is why we use `*...*` earmuffs: to create a separate namespace which loudly identifies these non-lexically-scoped variables, preventing us from accidentally converting lexical variables in our code into special variables.)

If we hide the existence of `*param*`, behind a function, we lose this flexibility; we have reduced it to a dumb global that can only be clobbered with calls to `assign-param`.

The `assign-param` function says to me (even after being fixed to use `setf` with `defvar` on the outside), "I don't understand Lisp and I'm scared of global variables from my experience with other languages".